# How to draw two lines between text

Tags: tables

How to draw two lines between text as shown in this picture. This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}



\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
Algorithm Use iteration to find general solution
\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
fator $a$,$b$
$y=a+bx$
\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The example that you show is using the `listings` package. See the example in the page 7. In the manual of the package. Listings.pdf

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest an alternative. Use `algorithmic` package where you can find more information here [Algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms). Two images are generated: one from your code, the other is an example based on OP image.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

% Your code

\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}
Algorithm Use iteration to find general solution

\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}

factor $a$,$b$

$y=a+bx$

\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}

% alternative

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Use iteration to find the general solution of the ODE in Example 1.4}\label{abc}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE factor \textbf{a,b};
\STATE {\textbf {y:=a+b*x}};
\FOR {\textbf{n:=1:4 do write}}
\STATE {\textbf{y:=a+b*x-int(int(y,x),x)}}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]